# Sending command line arguments to an already running python script

Tags: python

Sending command line arguments to an already running python script,,

basically if you have locked a script to be single instance, if the script is called again is there a way to forward the new arguments to the first starting instance?

is there an event or something similar i can use to detect if another instance of the script is trying to run and grab the cmd args?

Comment: What is the script doing? You can make an interactive script (one that responds to events) in many ways, sounds like thats what you're looking for.

Comment: its ment to run as a background process logging data, temp and weather sensors and write them once an hour. i want to call the program with a command line to send me the logs. as such it will be already running in the background and i want to refer the command line args to the background instance and cancel any new instance

Comment: It sounds like you want two different scripts: one for the background process that logs the data and one that you call that returns the logs.

Comment: i was thinking of doing it in like how a service works